# How to increase the number of color in gnuplot?

Tags: matplotlib, colors, data-visualization, gnuplot, color-palette

I have a file with 16 data blocks separated by two blank lines so that I can plot each block by selecting its index. What I would like to do is to give a different color to each data block automatically so I tried:

```
plot "data.csv" using 2:1:-2 lc var
```

The problem is that there are not enough color for all the 16 data blocks i.e some data set have the same color while I would like to associate a unique color to each data block automatically? Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to take N slices from the color palette.  You can define the color palette in many different ways, but so long as no color repeats in the palette this method will give you N distinct colors.

You ask specifically about 16 colors, so a minimal example using the default palette would be:

```
N = 16
plot for [i= 0 : N-1] "data.csv" index i using 2:1 lc palette frac (i * 1./N)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could select the colours, automatically or not.

The `linecolor` (or `lc`) specifier can take

- an integer to select one of the builtin line types and its
  associated colour,
- a colour name as a string, such as "blue" (in an interactive gnuplot
  session, do `show colors` to see the full list of available colour
  names),
- a colorspec (this can take many forms, do `help colorspec` for more
  details).

I took the laziest approach I could think of, which is to select colours at random!

I provided to `lc` a colorspec of the following form:

```
rgbcolor <integer val>  # integer value representing AARRGGBB
```

In the script below, the `<integer val>` are generated randomly,
in the range [000000, FFFFFF], where
FFFFFF (base 16) = 16**6-1 (base 10) = 16777215 (base 10).
This selects colours at random within the set of all possible colours
gnuplot supports, ignoring transparency (the AA in AARRGGBB).

```
unset key
set xrange [0:10]

seed = 4
x = rand(seed)
N = 16**6-1

plot for [i=1:16] x*i lc rgbcolor rand(0)*N
```

`rand(0)` gives a number between 0 and 1 so `rand(0)*N` gives a number between 0 and 16**6-1.

Since the seed is fixed (I picked 4), the sequence of random numbers and the set of
colours is the same every time you run the script. You can try
different seeds until all the line colours look different enough.

With the above script, I get this plot:
[image]